# How to parse Json string in c# using Json.net?

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I got this following code that retrieves data from my web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;


namespace BlogIT
{
    public partial class BlogPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public BlogPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // listbox vullen met alle posts
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/blog/api";

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "posts";
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.Method = Method.GET;

            client.ExecuteAsync<List<CreatePost>>(request, (response)
                =>
                {
                    if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Error
                        && response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var x = response.Content;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error occured.");
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Var x contains the following Json string:

```
[
    {"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen",
    "postId":1,
    "titel":"TestPost"
    },

    {"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen2",
    "postId":2,
    "titel":"TestPost2"
    },

    {"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen3",
    "postId":3,
    "titel":"TestPost3"
    }
]
```

The first question is how to loop trough this Json string and put it into an array
so the array[0] contains

```
{"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen",
    "postId":1,
    "titel":"TestPost"
    }
```

array[1] contains

```
{"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen2",
    "postId":2,
    "titel":"TestPost2"
    }
```

and array[2] contains

```
{"blog": 
        {"blogNaam":"Kevinsblog",
         "owner":
             {"username":"Kevin"}
        },
    "postbeschrijving":"Dit is een post om te testen3",
    "postId":3,
    "titel":"TestPost3"
    }
```

and the second question is how to access these values once they're put into an array so i can put them into a listbox in my WP7 app

If any other code is needed, just ask.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html ?  There are examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very straightforward.  First create some classes to match the JSON:

```
public class Post
{
    public Blog blog { get; set; }
    public string postbeschrijving { get; set; }
    public int postId { get; set; }
    public string titel { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public string blogNaam { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize into an array of those:

```
Post[] posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post[]>(x);
```

Now your data is contained in the array and you can access it as you normally would, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("post " + i);
    Console.WriteLine("blogNaam:" + posts[i].blog.blogNaam);
    Console.WriteLine("username:" + posts[i].blog.owner.username);
    Console.WriteLine("postbeschrijving:" + posts[i].postbeschrijving);
    Console.WriteLine("postId:" + posts[i].postId);
    Console.WriteLine("titel:" + posts[i].titel);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
}
```

Assuming `x` contains the JSON from your question, the above would give the following output if run in a console application:

```
post 0
blogNaam:Kevinsblog
username:Kevin
postbeschrijving:Dit is een post om te testen
postId:1
titel:TestPost
-----
post 1
blogNaam:Kevinsblog
username:Kevin
postbeschrijving:Dit is een post om te testen2
postId:2
titel:TestPost2
-----
post 2
blogNaam:Kevinsblog
username:Kevin
postbeschrijving:Dit is een post om te testen3
postId:3
titel:TestPost3
-----
```